# CUT R - Traspose Data Frame

Tags: r, cut

Working with the iris data set I want to generate 4 ranges and dispose them in columns. Besides, I would like to have 4 additional columns with the quantities contained in each range.

I'm giving you the code for what I've done so far to get the information.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(iris)[ , bins := cut(Sepal.Length,4), by = list(Species)]
setDT(iris)[ , bins_n := table(bins), by = list(Species)]

table(iris[iris$Species=='setosa',]$bins)

(4.9,5.65] (5.65,6.4] (6.4,7.15] (7.15,7.9] 
9         19         17          5 

iris2<-data.frame(species="setosa",D1="(4.9,5.65]",D2="(5.65,6.4]",D3="(6.4,7.15]",D4="(7.15,7.9]",C1=9,C2=19,C3=17,C4=5)
```

So, the final output would be

```
  species         D1         D2         D3         D4 C1 C2 C3 C4
1  setosa (4.9,5.65] (5.65,6.4] (6.4,7.15] (7.15,7.9]  9 19 17  5
```

Even better if I can add the other Species with its ranges below.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We could do a `stack` and reshape it to 'wide' from the 'tbl' output

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(stack(as.list(tbl)))[, species := "setosa"], 
   species ~ rowid(species), value.var = c("ind","values"))
```

If we want it for all the 'species'

```
dcast(iris[, .(C =.N), .((D = bins),Species)],
     Species ~ rowid(Species), value.var = c("D", "C"), sep="")
#      Species         D1         D2         D3         D4 C1 C2 C3 C4
#1:     setosa (6.4,7.15] (5.65,6.4] (4.9,5.65] (7.15,7.9] 17 19  9  5
#2: versicolor (7.15,7.9] (6.4,7.15] (5.65,6.4] (4.9,5.65]  9 15 20  6
#3:  virginica (5.65,6.4] (6.4,7.15] (7.15,7.9] (4.9,5.65] 22 15 11  2
```

#### data

```
tbl <- table(iris[iris$Species=='setosa',]$bins)
```

Comment: I tried to replicate the code but the next error appears: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds.

Comment: > tbl <- table(iris[iris$Species=='setosa',]$bins)
> 
> library(data.table)
> dcast(setDT(stack(as.list(tbl)))[, species := "setosa"], 
+       species ~ rowid(species), value.var = c("ind","values"))
Error in stack.default(as.list(tbl)) : 
  at least one vector element is required

Comment: It is based on your example and it is working fine for me

Comment: I solved by this way.  ver<-iris[, .(C =.N), .((D = bins),Species)]

a<-dcast(ver, Species ~ rowid(Species,prefix="range"), value.var = "D",sep="",fill= NA)
b<-dcast(ver, Species ~ rowid(Species,prefix="cant"), value.var = "C",sep="",fill= NA)

db2 <- data.frame(cbind(a, b), check.names = FALSE)
db2[, unique(colnames(db2))]

Comment: Can you check the R version and data.table version.  I have R 3.5.0 and data.table_1.11.2

Comment: R version 3.4.1 and data.table   * 1.10.5. I should update my version then